# How to change Java/JVM version in Weblogic

Tags: java, web-applications, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, application-server

WebLogic Server Version: 10.3.0.0

I face the below issue while trying to deploy my application in WebLogic,

[image]

I suspect it is due to JVM(1.6 internal JVM) used by WebLogic server , So i planned to upgrade it to 1.7.

Could you please let me know, how to change the JVM version/path in WebLogic server.

Thanks,

Comment: Just take a look into setWLSEnv script file. You have to change JAVA_HOME (PATH probably also) to the one you want to use it before starting WebLogic.

Answer (score 1):

WebLogic 10.3.0 is not supported on JDK 1.7:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13196_01/platform/suppconfigs/configs103/103_over/overview.html

You will need to compile your code using JDK 1.6 or upgrade to a newer version of WebLogic.